# SQL Server: Convert a varchar to a datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like a date in a `varchar(255)` data type as below to be converted to a `datetime` or `date` format

```
05 jun 2007
```

When I use a cast with either the datetime or date:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[SSIS_TempDump_Episode_Numbers] 
SET DischargeDate = CAST([Discharge date] as Date)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

or alter column gives me the same result. is it because of the date format?

Comment: Is your `[Discharge date]` of a `varchar` type that represents date in format `05 jun 2007`?

Comment: It works just fine with the value you have there. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32126). There are probably other rows where the format is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yes [Discharge date] is the varchar(255) that represents the format 05 jun 2007

Comment: See the Mikael Eriksson`s comment.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson yes your correct i found a rogue entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select CONVERT(datetime,'05 jun 2007') -->'2007-06-05 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @foo VARCHAR(255)

SET @foo = '05 jun 2007'

PRINT CONVERT(DATETIME,@foo)
```